# pointer arrays to String

Tags: swift, pointers

I need to have a pointer array like in C, in Swift.

The following code works:

```swift
let ptr = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Int32>.allocate(capacity: 5)
ptr[0] = 1
ptr[1] = 5

print(ptr[0], ptr[1]) // outputs 1 5
```

The following code, however, does not work:

```swift
let ptr = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<String>.allocate(capacity: 5)

print(ptr[0]) // Outputs an empty string (as expected)
print(ptr[1]) // Just exits with exit code 11
```

When I do `print(ptr[1])` in the swift REPL, I get the following output:

```
Execution interrupted. Enter code to recover and continue.
Enter LLDB commands to investigate (type :help for assistance.)
```

How can I create a C-like array with Strings (or any other reference type, as this also doesn't seem to work with classes).

What should I adjust?

Comment: You've allocated a buffer that can store 5 strings, but you haven't actually stored 5 instances in it. The contents are uninitialized, so you're just observing whatever garbage was left in the memory before you had it. The `Unsafe` in `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer` isn't coincidental.

Comment: @Alexander I see, so that's why I can't  index it. I'm guessing `storeBytes(of:toByteOffset:as:)` could be the solution instead of indexing it

Comment: You can index it (the pointer), it's just that what you'll find at the destination is random junk. What exactly are you trying to achieve with this pointer? You could probably achieve the same thing more easily by just making an regular `Array<String>` and getting a pointer to the array's buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the memory with valid `String` data.

```
let values = ["First", "Last"]
let umbp = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<String>.allocate(capacity: values.count)
_ = umbp.initialize(from: values)
print(umbp.map { $0 })

umbp[0] = "Joe"
umbp[1] = "Smith"

print(umbp.map { $0 })
```

Prints:

```
["First", "Last"]
["Joe", "Smith"]
```

Comment: What I did was create an `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<String?>` and then `umbp.initialize(repeating: nil)`. Works like a charm. Thanks!